# Docker root folders on Windows location

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that has a /data volume and it is specified like this:

/data:/data

This works perfectly fine. The problem is I don't know where /data on the host is (host is Windows 10). Under Linux this is perfectly fine and the folder /data can be found in the root folder.

I did a search using PowerShell, like this

ls c:\ *subdirectory-of-data* -Recurse -Directory

through all drives, but no luck.

I'm using the native Docker for Windows (not Docker Tools) and I'm using docker-compose up through PowerShell.

So where does /data reside if the host is Windows?

Comment: Are you using `git bash` as console?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of docker is mounted on the persistent Virtual Disk of the VM which is under `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx`, it seems can't edit the file in the VM directly on windows, but you could use `cp` to copy it out.

```
docker cp CONTAINER:FILEPATH LOCALFILEPATH
```

Edit the file and copy it back.

```
docker cp LOCALFILEPATH CONTAINER:FILEPATH
```